# Form1 DataGridView Copy To Form2 DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to get where I select a row in datagridview click Create then it will copy that row's specific cells to form2 (without making a new form or overwriting existing data) basically like a Purchase Order. I can make it do exactly what I need to do with 2 Datagridviews on the same Form with

```
           //THIS WORKS FOR DATAGRIDVIEWS ON SAME FORM//
        if (this.dataGridView2.DataSource != null)
         {
             this.dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
         }
          else
         {
           // this.dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
         {
             int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
             dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

             dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
             dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

But will not work when the same controls are on Form2. I need it to work this way but transfer (copy) to the FrmMetalKit (Form2)

[Here is what the image looks like going from Main Form1 to FrmMetalKit (Form2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC0vA.jpg)

Comment: The cleanest, smartest, best thing to do is have each DGV share the same DataSource, perhaps thru a (filtered) `DataView`, then data will appear to flip between the 2 controls instantly.  Since it looks like you are storing data directly in the control(s) you may need to first learn about the marvels of DataBinding.

Comment: My main form is all MySql based from getting information from the database of the server. Adding/Updating/Deleting, I have been trying for a couple days now to just do what i need to but same time I did not code this the way some do with controls, I dont have any Databinding data, or tables or anything within the inside of the program... it's all called and directed from the server side without these built in controls visual studio has.

Comment: It is unclear how the grids are originally filled with data. I am confident binding the grids to a data source will make things easier, however if you prefer to create more work for yourself… is there something preventing you from passing the grid in form 1 to form 2?

Comment: I can pass between the 2 forms but only if its like FrmMetal fr2 = new FrmMetal but it only adds one row to that form as the code entails instead of if i clicked on another row to add it then it will pop up a new form and add that one instead of adding it a single instance of the FrmMetal -